# Magento Question

Tags: magento

Hello
When I try to give media url in catagory-> description like this.

```
<img src="{{media url="/HD53_1.jpg"}}" alt="" />
```

so image doesn't display at front end because when i see html code of this image src in WYSIWYG editor then it give wrong path.

so plz give me correct way to give media url

Comment: I don't get it ... what do you really want? the correct image code? or when you are in the designer, and select an image it doesnt show the right one?

Answer (score 0):

Click the `WYSIWYG editor` button, then click on the image button (looks like a tree). Then click the icon to the right of the `Image URL` field (looks like a folder).  Use the Media Uploader to save your new image to the server, then select on the newly-uploaded image and click Insert Image.    Change back to the Insert Image popup and click `Insert`. Submit and Save.

Answer (score 0):

How about these :

```
$mainImage = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'test' . DS . 'image.jpg';
// will show http://example.com/media/test/image.jpg
```

or

```
Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
// will show http://example.com/media/
```

In CMS pages should be :

```
{{store direct_url=media}}
// this will produce http://www.example.com/media
```

Outside of the CMS pages :

```
{{store direct_url=media/store/cms/brands/brand_logo.gif}}
// this will produce  http://www.example.com/media/store/cms/brands/brand_logo.gif
```

Answer (score 0):

use Mage::getBaseDir('media') this function for get media folder url path and 'DS' for separator of folder.
like Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'your folder';